# How can I change the year-postfix separator in apacite?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I'm trying to format my citations such that they look like:

> (Author, Year: page)

instead of

> (Author, Year, page)

I've tried redefining the year-postfix separator, `\renewcommand{\BBN}{\colon\space}` but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm not sure whether this requires a MWE, but:

#### main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4size,oneside,titlepage,12pt]{book}  
\usepackage{apacite}  
\begin{document}  
... \cite[page]{AUTHOR2014}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

#### references.bib

```
@BOOK{AUTHOR2014,
     Year = {2014},
     Author = {Author, Some},
     Title = {A title},
     Publisher = {A publisher},
     Address = {A place}
% ... blah  
}
```

Comment: For those of us who aren't already thoroughly familiar with the citation call-out format produced by `apacite`, please indicate what the default citation call-outs look like, and please indicate what exactly you would like to change. I somehow doubt that what you want is an *italicized* "and", but that's what you've written so far. By the way, a real MWE would be quite helpful; your current posting is *not* an MWE.

Comment: @Mico apologies; I've edited the post.

Comment: I agree with you that modifying the `\BBN` macro ought to be the way to achieve your objective. I'm afraid I'm stymied as well, i.e., I can't get the recommended method to work either. Could well be a bug in the package. :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `\renewcommand{\BBN}{:\space}` after `\begin{document}` it works.

e.g., this MWE works as required:

```
\documentclass[a4size,oneside,titlepage,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents} 

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib} @BOOK{AUTHOR2014,
  Year = {2014},
  Author = {Author, Some},
  Title = {A title},
  Publisher = {A publisher},
  Address = {A place}} 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BBN}{:\space}

Here's some text \cite[p.~53]{AUTHOR2014}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use something like `\AtBeginDocument{...}`? And why does it have to be *after* `\begin{document}`?